# A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'. My react-native-reanimated version: "^2.8.0"

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm getting this error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> Could not get unknown property 'rnMinorVersion' for project ':react-native-reanimated' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I tried updating react-native-reanimated version to 3.0.0-rc.0 still it's not working for me.

My package.json:

```
dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  }
```